# Application python.exe had been blocked from accessing graphics devices - OpenCL

Tags: python, windows, opencl, nvidia

I have an OpenCL programm [here](https://github.com/john-hu/gpgpu/tree/master/opencl/trade). It works good at Intel integrated GPU but not at NVidia GTX950M. The question is "my windows 10 always saying my app is blocked". These are what I had done and found:

1. I got a GPU crash in my Windows 10 only if I increase work items. So, I had googled a lot of docs about this topic. It only happens to the GPU time exceeded 2 seconds. So, I found TdrDelay registry to increase the size.
2. After increasing the TdrDelay, I got the "blocked from accessing graphics devices" issue. Again, I had googled that.
3. Someone said that I should upgrade the NVidia driver. I had done that but no luck.
4. Someone said that I should slow down the GPU and GPU memory clock through MSI Afterburner. I had tried that and still no luck.

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue???

My working environment is a Windows PC with the following spec:

- CPU: Intel i7 6700HQ
- GPU: Intel 540 HD and NVidia GTX 950M (with 2G RAM)
- RAM: 8G
- OS: Windows 10
- Programming Language: python with pyopencl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer finally. We are pretty close to the answer: TdrDelay.

In Windows, there is another registry key to disable TDR (Timeout Detection and Recovery): [TdrLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569918(v=vs.85).aspx). Once this registry key set to 0, Windows totally disables the TDR function.

Hope this can help other......  :)